# How to structure Vite's resulting "dist" tree for use by Python's Flask

Tags: flask, vite

Flask looks for templates within a 'templates' folder, and static files, generally, in a 'static' folder. The 'templates' requirement is more strict than the 'static' requirement, since relative paths can just be used within a template to serve any arbitrary path to a static file - so the issue I'm having stems from the 'templates' requirement. What I am trying to do is build my vite project such that the resulting 'dist' directory is in the appropriate setup to run a flask server.

I have configured the vite.config.js file such that the output is thrown into a dist/templates directory instead of just the default dist. This solves the issue of having my templates in a folder titled 'templates', but the issue now is that the script tag to my main javascript file will only work either in dev mode OR build mode, since the path in dev mode (before building vite) is relative to the index.html file that it is called from, and the path from my flask file points to project/dist/ (as set up in my flask app instantiation).

So basically, flask will look in the "project/dist/" directory for my main.js because that is where I tell it to find the templates folder, but it really needs to look in "project/dist/templates/"... but I am not sure changing flask configs is the right way to go about this, I suspect there is some magic I can perform in the vite.config.js which would make this all easier. But my google-foo has failed me up to this point, so I am here asking for help. I will share the relevant development stuff below for reference, and I will answer any questions as fast as I can. Thank you.

This is the ideal dist output tree of my dreams:

```
-project
---dist
------templates
---------index.html
------static
---------{asset files that can be referenced from index.html with "../static/filename"}
```

This is my current general development project tree:

```
-flask-app.py
-project
---dist\templates
------{output files}
---index.html
---main.js
```

Here is my vite.config.js:

```
export default {
    build: {
        target: 'esnext',
        rollupOptions: {
          input: {
            app: 'index.html',
          },
          output: {
            dir: './dist/templates'
          }
        },
      },
    base: './'
  }
```

This is the script tag in the head of my index.html file:

```
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

Here is my Flask setup:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, root_path='project/dist/')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

tldr: I would like to configure my vite.config.js file such that the resulting dist folder tree is setup in a way that is easy to use from a flask application.

So far I've tried the following:

- Changing the output.dir in vite.config.js (as seen currently in my config file)
- Silly, but tried changing the base to a few different things in an attempt to point at the correct filed from flask, this failed.
- Reading docs and other people's questions, but I haven't found a clear or close enough solution